# Custom color for UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, pixate

I'm usinge pixate in order to customize my app and I have a little problem.
I read the doc and the class for UITableVIew is called `table-view-cell`. I thought that if I created a class named like this I wouldn't have to manually had the class to the cells ? Am I right ?

My css code :

```
.table-view-cell {
    background-color: red;
}
```

Tried this too :

```
.table-view-cell content-view{
    background-color: red;
}
```

None of them works .. But if I had classes manually it works just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a globally available style like this:

```
table-view-cell{
  background-color: #900;
}
```

Or you can put a `styleClass` attribute on a `UITableView` and target its children:

```
.yourTable table-view-cell{
  background-color:#900;
}
```

This works for me.

Comment: Wow just a little f*** dot, and an afternoon wasted .. Thank you ;)

Comment: Haha... yep. That's programming for you. :)